# Exception type created class used in another

Tags: java, class, exception

I can't seem to find a way to fix this. I have a class called CardException which extends Exception. The only code it has is:

```
public class CardException extends Exception{

String erro;

public CartaoException(String erro){
    this.erro = erro;
}
}
```

Now I have another class with a method in which I want to throw an Exception if the condition is false:

```
public void changePin(int pin, int newPin){
    try{
        if(pin == getPin()){
            setPin(newPin);
        }
    } catch (CardException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

but I'm getting an error at "catch (CardException e)" saying:
"Unreachable catch block for CardException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body" and I have no idea why.

The point is to create a class called **CardException** of *Exception* type, with a constructor that receives an error message as argument. Then, on my other class, I need to create that method **changePin** which receives the old pin and a new pin and, if the old pin doesn't match the one already saved, it has to throw and exception with a message: "Invalid pin".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java compiler is intelligent enough to determine whether the statements inside `try` blocks are prone to a checked exception or not. As no statement in your `try` block seems to cause `CardException`, hence compiler complains.

Just for the sake of testing, if you add `throws` clause with `CardException` to either of your `getPin`/`setPin` method, then compiler will not complain as those methods can throw the exception in `catch` block.

Answer (score 1):

Since `CardException` extends `Exception`, not `RuntimeException`, it is considered a *checked exception*. What that means is that all methods from which the exception is thrown *must* declare the exception in their `throws` declaration clause.

Because of this requirement Java compilers can check if a code block throws a particular checked exception or not:

- If there is a `throws` block inside the code body that throws this exception or one of its subclasses, the `catch` is valid
- If any of the functions called inside the code body is declared as throwing the exception or one of its subclasses, the `catch` is valid
- Otherwise, the catch is invalid, and the compiler issues an error.

You would need to catch this exception if `getPin` or `setPin` threw it. In this case, however, the functions would need to add a `throws CardException` to their declarations.